# Why does a single value work as a condition

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Obviously, in conditional statements you need to make sure a true or false value is returned to either execute or skip the block of code associated with the if statement. How does a single value serve as a true Boolean in python? I'm not sure if this is a universal for all languages but I've discovered it in python 3.x.

Example:

```
value = 1
if value:
   print("value == True") # prints every time
```

I'd expect the compiler to complain or just return false. Why does the compiler perceive `if value` as true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer or floats values other than 0 are treated as True:

```
In [8]: bool(int(1))
Out[8]: True

In [9]: bool(int(0))
Out[9]: False

In [10]: bool(int(-1))
Out[10]: True


In [16]: bool(float(1.2e4))
Out[16]: True

In [17]: bool(float(-1.4))
Out[17]: True

In [20]: bool(0.0)
Out[20]: False

In [21]: bool(0.000001)
Out[21]: True
```

Similarly, empty lists, sets, dicts, empty string, None, etc are treated as false:

```
In [11]: bool([])
Out[11]: False

In [12]: bool({})
Out[12]: False

In [13]: bool(set())
Out[13]: False

In [14]: bool("")
Out[14]: False

In [19]: bool(None)
Out[19]: False
```

Comment: also `None` and of course `False`. Might also provide a link to the relevant [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: Is there a reason just 0 returns false and why give non Boolean values Boolean values?

Comment: @AdamSmith Just added None and floats values as well.

Comment: Also what is the benefits over using a let's say "real" Boolean value over a "fake" Boolean value if they are both capable of the same things?

Comment: @JGerulskis What do you mean? Build in types can be used as booleans. For example to add to list if is empty or not: `if a_list: print("List not empty")`

Comment: @Marcin For eample if 0 returns false you could simply modify a integer variable to perform the same task as a boolean. `While x: x = false` will do the same as `While x: x = 0`

Comment: Yes you could, buts you shouldn't be replacing bool values with integers for no reason. Its just a convenience.